# Django Session Not Working on Heroku

Tags: django, session, heroku

I've written a simple voting app based on the Django tutorial.  I want to limit the number of votes per visitor to one, so I have used Django's middleware sessions.  I'm completely new to sessions, but I was able to get something working on my local machine.  Unfortunately, once I pushed it to Heroku, it stopped working.  I saw a few other SO articles regarding this issue when you have multiple dynos, but I am on a Hobby account with just 1 dyno, so...

Here's the logic in my views.py:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    if request.session.get('has_voted', False):
        return render(request, 'poll/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': ("You've already voted."),
            })
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'poll/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "Make sure to select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        request.session['has_voted'] = True
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results', args=(question.id,)))
```

The session logic comes almost verbatim from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/), and my settings.py is correctly configured.  Is there a special configuration for Heroku that I missed?  Do I need to add something to my settings.py after all?  I'm at a loss since there is no actual error.  It just fails silently...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What sort of `SESSION_ENGINE` are you using in your `settings.py`? On Heroku, Dynos restart all the time, and should be treated as ephemeral resources.

To combat this, you should probably use `SESSION_ENGINE= 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'`. This will ensure your session data gets persisted to your database on Heroku (you are using [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql), right?)

Comment: Thank you!  I am using Heroku Postgres. I hadn't configured SESSION_ENGINE at all.  I assumed the default would be fine. I added the above line, and it appears to be working now. 

The documentation mentions setting CACHES, but I wasn't entirely sure how to configure it. Is that necessary?  

Also, is there a good way to test to make sure that, when the dyno restarts, the session will still be persisted?

Comment: Heyo! So, you'll also want to set your caching settings as well =) Reading through the docs there will give you an understanding of what to use based on what setup you have. If you want to test your sessions out right now, you can start a session, then say `heroku ps:restart` to force your dynos to restart, after which you can make another request.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so much for your help.