# Why are sessions not being persisted in my Django app?

Tags: django, heroku, session-cookies, django-authentication, heroku-postgres

I have a Django (1.11.8) application running on a staging server on Heroku.

I imported the database with existing records, users, etc and it all seems to be working fine.

When I sign in, I am sometimes returned to the sign in page. Other times I am signed in and I'm redirected to the user profile page. However, if I do anything after that I end up getting signed out.

I tried making sure the name of the cookies don't clash with the production application (which works fine).

I also inspected Session records via the shell. When I manage to sign in, it doesn't look like it's creating any new session records. To be sure I cleared all the session records and no new ones get created when I sign in.

The database connection seems fine, as I'm able to create a user record by signing up. I've also been able to manually create a session record via the shell. I just don't see any being created as a result of the sign in page.

Any ideas appreciated?

Edit:

So in installed apps I'm using:

`'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sessions'`

Engine:

`SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"`

In middleware:

`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',`

EDIT2: OH.

OK, so I read up on the session engine thing:

`SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions

Since I'm using the cache and not the db in development that would explain why I don't see anything happening in the DB. I'm guessing there's an issue with the cache in Heroku.

Comment: Maybe some code showing what you do could help. It could be anything

Comment: For starters, we would need to know what session engine your using in your settings.

Comment: kl I've added in some setup details, bit of a django noob so let me know if there's any more relevant info I should add

Comment: I'm more convinced there's something in the environment than the code though, as this all works fine locally and in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out cache storage doesn't work on Heroku, this answer cleared it all up: [Django Session Not Working on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963506/django-session-not-working-on-heroku)