# Django Session Is not working with Heroku when changing views (but works locally)

Tags: django, heroku, django-sessions

The sessions work perfectly while changing views when working locally, but when deployed to Heroku it is as if the session was refreshed and all the information it contains is deleted upon every view change. I am using Heroku's Postgres Database.

I have already taken a look at: [Django Session Not Working on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963506/django-session-not-working-on-heroku)
but the problem still persists

Here is my current settings file. Any help would be appreciated

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


SECRET_KEY = 'e488a0185303170daa47fe1de243823fbb3db60f045e6eae'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'here goes the heroku host']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '....',
    '....',

]
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'System.asgi.application'
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'System.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'System.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
 }
import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

SESSION_ENGINE= 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {'min_length': 8}
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'authentication.validators.NumericValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'authentication.validators.UppercaseValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'authentication.validators.LowercaseValidator',
    },

]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'authentication/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/authentication/media/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

[Caching and CSRF](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-memcache#caching-and-csrf)

You cannot cache any views or fragments that contain forms with CSRF tokens because the token changes with each request. For the sake of learning how to use Django’s integrated caching we will disable Django’s CSRF middleware. Since this task list is public, this is not a big deal but do not do this in any serious production application.

Comment CsrfViewMiddleware in django_tasklist/settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

[Connecting to Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#connecting-in-python)

Did you install psycopg2 and dj-database-url and add it to your requirements.txt?

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

`pip install dj-database-url`